# Git ignores its settings, does not use pager and colors

Tags: git

I have git repository on remote server and when I log in over SSH and do *git diff* it uses neither pager nor it show diff in color.

I tried setting git setting for ui.color and core.pager but it does not seems to have effect. I tried it on local, global and system level, but it has no effect. I have verified with strace that it's able to find and read those configuration files, but for some reason it ignores settings from there.

Strangely, if I export env variable GIT_PAGER='less -r' then git uses pager. But I still can't force it to show output in colors.

Git version is 1.7.9.5.

Any idea why is that so?

Comment: Are you sure you're the right user on the remote?

Comment: @rholmes, what do you mean by that?

Comment: What is remote OS, what terminal are you using? what does `tput colors` show?

Comment: When you ssh to the server, you're using the git config and settings of the user you authenticated with, on that server...

Comment: @Doon, Ubuntu 12.04. tput colors shows 8

Comment: @rholmes, yes, root. When I go into repository and type git config --list, among many options I can find following also
`ui.color=true`
`core.pager=less`
`push.default=current`, etc.

`git diff --color HEAD^` also works, but it does not want to use colors itself (without providing option --color), although git config says it should.

Comment: Do these settings match what's in /root/.gitconfig?  Is your $HOME directory set to /root (as one would expect for root user)?